# A quick visual riddle to distract me from all this snow

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge

The images below can be connected by a single word.

[image: A Pin]

[image: A Hand Pointing a Finger]

[image: A Dodge Viper]

[image: The bottom of a Foot]

[image: A Line Graph]

[image: An Empty Apartment]

[image: A Piece of Raw Meat]

[image: A Paint Brush and a Pot of Red Paint]

What is the word and what are the connections?

Comment: So many allusions, in one word?  Thought it was erf and then woof and then saddle. All wrong of course. How many letters?

Comment: @lauir Yes.  And I actually held few back to keep it interesting, but I'll stick them in hints if this goes unsolved, though I doubt that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The connection is

> BALL

and the words are

> PINball

,

> ballPOINT

,

> DODGEball (thanks for the hint)

,

> FOOTball

,

> CURVEball

,

> ballROOM

,

> MEATball

, and

> PAINTball

Comment: You got it Will. +1

Comment: I guess you could say the paint color was a RED herring...

Comment: What is a dodgeball? Can someone explain?

Comment: It's a game (*[and a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DodgeBall:_A_True_Underdog_Story)* (Wikipedia), not to be confused (as I did) with *[Rollerball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollerball_(1975_film))* (Wikipedia)).

Answer (score 4):

The word is

> point

Needle:

> Its end is a point.

Hand:

> The finger is in the act of pointing.

Car:

> The point system in driving is a system of demerits for driving offenses.

Foot:

> The picture shows the reflexology points of the foot.

Curve:

> The point of inflection is where the curve changes from curving upward to curving downward.

Picture of room:

> The picture shows perspective with a vanishing point in the middle.

Meat:

> A point cut of beef is the second cut of the beef brisket.

Paint:

> Some paint brushes have a pointed tip.

Comment: Some good connections +1 but the answer's not "point".  There's a much better fit (although one clue is a bit cruel...  I think I'll add the knowledge tag actually, though the remaining clues should be sufficient.

Comment: The car seems to be  Dodge Challenger.  A classic muscle car and a superb play on words.

Comment: @lauir Huh...  Y'know...  I'm so bad with cars, I thought it was a Dodge Viper.  Doesn't really mater though.

Answer (score 0):

Word can also be

> Right

Connections:

1. Needle

> The Needle is pointing towards the right direction.

2. Hand

> Tha hand is also pointing to the right direction.

3. Car

> The car is coming from the right direction.

4. Foot

> If a person at your front, show you his right foot, so it looks like that in the image.

5. Curve

> The curve is going towards the right.

6. Room

> The door of the room is on the right wall.

7. Meat

> Not sure about it, but maybe the meat is sliced in right manner.

8. Paint

> Paintbrush is used by our right hand.

Comment: Sorry but right's not right.  There's a better connection to be had.